# Using pandas, index error

Tags: pandas, indexing, rounding

I am trying to round numbers, if their decimal numbers end with (125, 375, 625, 875), I replace them with (25, 25, 75, 75).
My code is:

```
import pandas as pd  

inpExcelFile = 'Lat Lon Coordinates and soil.csv'  #lat, lon
gridCells = pd.read_csv(inpExcelFile)
#inpExcelFile can be downloaded from "http://www.evernote.com/l/AWMD9Le15ytJmokhnUF8r84vtXVIsj2_lBQ/"

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lat_ext', 'lon_ext', 'lat_close', 'lon_close'])

for i in range(0, len(gridCells.index)):  

    if str(df.at[i, 'lat_ext'])== str('125'):
       df.at[i, 'lat_close'] =  float((str(gridCells.at[i, 'lat'])[:3]) + str('25'))
    if str(df.at[i, 'lat_ext'])== str('375'):
       df.at[i, 'lat_close'] = float((str(gridCells.at[i, 'lat'])[:3]) + str('25'))
    if str(df.at[i, 'lat_ext'])== str('625'):
       df.at[i, 'lat_close'] = float((str(gridCells.at[i, 'lat'])[:3]) + str('75'))
    if str(df.at[i, 'lat_ext'])== str('875'):
       df.at[i, 'lat_close'] = float((str(gridCells.at[i, 'lat'])[:3]) + str('75'))

for j in range(0, len(gridCells.index)):  

    if str(df.at[j, 'lon_ext'])== str('125'):
       df.at[j, 'lon_close'] =  float((str(gridCells.at[j, 'lat'])[:3]) + str('25'))
    if str(df.at[j, 'lon_ext'])== str('375'):
       df.at[j, 'lon_close'] = float((str(gridCells.at[j, 'lat'])[:3]) + str('25'))
    if str(df.at[j, 'lon_ext'])== str('625'):
       df.at[j, 'lon_close'] = float((str(gridCells.at[j, 'lat'])[:3]) + str('75'))
    if str(df.at[j, 'lon_ext'])== str('875'):
       df.at[j, 'lon_close'] = float((str(gridCells.at[j, 'lat'])[:3]) + str('75'))

df.to_excel('cikti' + '.xlsx')
```

I am getting this error: "ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers"

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want to round decimals from x.125 to x.25, and so on. I'm not sure of any way to do that directly with floats, but here's a somewhat clunky approach to do it (via string-conversions) with print-outs after every step:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "number": [1.125, 1.375, 1.625, 1.875]
})
print df
```

DF:

```
   number
0   1.125
1   1.375
2   1.625
3   1.875
```

Convert numbers to string to deal with substrings (decimals, in this case)

```
df["number_as_string"] = df.number.map(str)
print df
```

DF:

```
   number number_as_string
0   1.125            1.125
1   1.375            1.375
2   1.625            1.625
3   1.875            1.875
```

Create column with decimals you want to map to

```
df.loc[df.number_as_string.str.endswith(".125"), "number_decimal"] = ".25"
df.loc[df.number_as_string.str.endswith(".375"), "number_decimal"] = ".25"
df.loc[df.number_as_string.str.endswith(".625"), "number_decimal"] = ".75"
df.loc[df.number_as_string.str.endswith(".875"), "number_decimal"] = ".75"
print df
```

DF:

```
   number number_as_string number_decimal
0   1.125            1.125            .25
1   1.375            1.375            .25
2   1.625            1.625            .75
3   1.875            1.875            .75
```

Using the strings, get the part of the number before the decimal point, and add your prefered decimals to it.

```
df["number_rounded"] = df.number_as_string.str.split(".").str[0] + df.number_decimal
print df
```

DF:

```
   number number_as_string number_decimal number_rounded
0   1.125            1.125            .25           1.25
1   1.375            1.375            .25           1.25
2   1.625            1.625            .75           1.75
3   1.875            1.875            .75           1.75
```

Convert that column to floats (from strings)

```
df["number_rounded"] = df.number_rounded.map(float)
print df
```

Final DF:

```
   number number_as_string number_decimal  number_rounded
0   1.125            1.125            .25            1.25
1   1.375            1.375            .25            1.25
2   1.625            1.625            .75            1.75
3   1.875            1.875            .75            1.75
```

Comment: I reached my goal with your answer, thank you, but what about my script? Can you see any point there?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, what do you mean with see any point? Honestly, I think your implementation is very un-pandas-y. You should try to avoid for-loops in pandas, as the vectorized operations are way faster, and frankly the entire point of pandas. At the very least, put all your logic into the same for loop, you're now looping the same thing twice.